# Irregular segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, cs50

I'm attempting to run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
        /* code */
        char senha [256];
        if (argv[1] != NULL)
        {
                strcpy(senha, argv[1]);
        }
        char frase [256];
        printf("Insira a frase: \n");
        scanf("%s", frase);
        int sizeS = (int)strlen(senha);
        int sizeF = (int)strlen(frase);
        char fraseout [sizeF+1];
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i=0; i<=sizeF-1; i++)
        {
                if(j>=sizeS)
                {
                        j=0;
                }
                int valF = (int)frase[i];
                int valS = (int)senha[j];
                valF = 32 + ((valF - 32) + (valS - 32)) % (128-32);
                fraseout[i] = (char)valF;
                j++;
        }
        fraseout[sizeF] = '\0';
        printf("\"%s\" -> \"%s\"\n", frase, fraseout);
        return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to run this on my Ubuntu 15.04 it compiles and runs perfectly. When I try to run it on a OSX Yosemite it also compiles and run flawlessly. If I, however, compile and run it on a CS50 VM although the compilation runs fine I get a Segmentation Fault error on Running. Why is this happening and why only on one singular OS?

Comment: Once you have any UB, anything can happen at any point. I'll write up all the UB I see.

Comment: you should use strncpy instead of strcpy, as your buffer is bound to 256 bytes; same thing for scanf, use "%256s" rather than "%s".

Comment: What is the value of **j** ?

Comment: @Snaipe **256** or **255** ?

Comment: @Arengorn When you say: **When I attempt to run this on my Ubuntu 15.04 it compiles and runs perfectly.** happens because you compile like this **gcc program.c -o program**. Until you learn better you should try this: **gcc -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion --std=c11 -O2 program.c -o program** .

Comment: @Snaipe There's practically no reason to ever use `strncpy` or `strncmp`. If you don't know the size of your buffer is good enough, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @o11c er, what ? Of course you need to use those, and even more so if you're dealing with some user input like argv (not to mention file formats that embed non-null-terminated strings like PE or ELF)

Comment: @Snaipe Truncating input is *always* the wrong thing to do. You should instead *make* the buffer is actually big enough - i.e., don't use fixed-size buffers.

Comment: @o11c right, but saying that one should *never* use strncpy or strncmp is plain wrong, this does not work as a general rule of thumb. Take the section table in the PE format, the name field is a char[8] that may or may *not* be null terminated, and you sure are going to be slapped by an out of bound access if you're not going to use the strn* function family. Same thing for strings passed over the network, those are usually not null-terminated, but prefixed by the length of the string, so not using those function is an gaping vulnerability.

Comment: @Snaipe in which case you *still* shouldn't use `strncpy`, but rather `memcpy` with an additional check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible issues, with irrelevant lines removed. The uninitialized ones are likely your problem.

`argv[1] != NULL` is safe with C89, but is obscure and might not be on noncompliant compilers. Checking `argc` is more typical.

`senha` is left uninitialized i f the argument is not passed, which may result in buffer overflows later.

```
        char senha [256];
        if (argv[1] != NULL)
                strcpy(senha, argv[1]);
```

Not checking the size of the buffer for input, use `scanf("%255s", frase);`

Not checking the return value of `scanf`, `frase` will be left uninitialized if it fails, which may result in buffer overflows later.

```
        char frase [256];
        scanf("%s", frase);
```

VLAs not in C89, but are in C99 and provided as an extension in GNU C89, which is the default used by gcc. This may fail to compile with strict C89 compilers.

```
        int sizeF = (int)strlen(frase);
        char fraseout [sizeF+1];
```

Not initialized.

```
    int j;
```

This computation may yield a `"`, resulting in improperly quoted output.

```
                valF = 32 + ((valF - 32) + (valS - 32)) % (128-32);
                fraseout[i] = (char)valF;
        printf("\"%s\" -> \"%s\"\n", frase, fraseout);
```

Answer (score 3):

The code works when j has an initial value of 0.  This is not to be assumed on all (or any) systems, however, hence the different behavior.  Initialize j.